In advaita, is the notion of saguna brahman meaningless?
To my understanding, Saguna brahman implies a perceiver who perceives the gunas of Brahman.  But in Advaita nothing exists except Brahman.

Saguna Brahman is Brahman conceived of as the Creator, Preserver and Destroyer of the Universe corresponding to Isvara. Advaita Vedanta, however, considers Nirguna Brahman as the only Reality. So what does Shankara think of Saguna Brahman or Isvara? Shankara writes the following in his Brahma Sutra Bhasya III.II.14:

'Hence in sentences of this kind, the formless Brahman alone, just as
It is spoken of by the texts themselves, has to be accepted. But the
other texts, speaking of Brahman with form, have injunctions about
meditations as their main objectives. So long as they do not lead to
some contradiction, their apparent meanings should be accepted. But
when they involve a contradiction, the principle to be followed for
deciding one or the other is that, those that have formless Brahman as
their main purport are more authoritative than the others which have
not that as their main purport. It is according to this that one is
driven to the conclusion that Brahman is formless and not its
opposite, though texts having both the purports are in evidence.'

Brahma Sutra Bhasya of Sri Sankaracharya III.II.14
What does Sankaracharya mean in the above quote?

Both Isvara and jiva are associated with maya; both are products of
maya. But the difference between them lies in the fact that maya is
under the control of Isvara, whereas the Jiva, or individualized
being, is under the control of maya. The limitations imposed by maya
upon the jiva make it totally forget its real nature; but Isvara
cannot be injured by His maya, as the cobra cannot be injured by its
poison. Both Isvara and jiva are manifestations of Brahman on the
relative plane; but Isvara is free, like a spider which moves freely
on its web, whereas the jiva is entangled in the world, like a
silkworm imprisoned in its cocoon. Isvara uses maya as His instrument
for the purpose of the creation, preservation, and dissolution of the
universe; through maya, again, He exercises His Lordship over it. But
the jiva is a slave of maya. It must never be forgotten that, from the
standpoint of Pure Brahman, maya is non-existent; therefore both
Isvara and jiva are non-existent from the standpoint of the Absolute.
Both are appearances. But on the relative plane the jiva is the
worshipper, and Isvara, the worshipped. Isvara is the Creator, and the
jiva, the created being. Isvara is the Father and Lord, and the jiva,
His child or servant. Though Isvara is one step lower than Brahman,
yet His importance in the relative world is beyond all measure. As a
matter of fact, since Brahman is the unrelated Absolute, It cannot be
an object of the jiva’s thought or adoration. Isvara, the Personal
God, derives His power and reality from Brahman and is the highest
conception of the Infinite that can be formed by the finite mind. When
the highest flight of spiritual experience is reached, then both the
individual soul and the Personal God merge in Brahman, and the three
become one. Brahman alone exists.

Introduction to Self-Knowledge (Atmabodha) by Swami Nikhilananda

No. It has a lot of meaning. The Meaning of Saguna Brahman is Nirguna Brahman. Saguna is a pointer to Nirguna. Advaita is the equivalence theory that states that set of Nirguna & Saguna is all one and is Parahbrahman which by definition is indescribable, unutterable etc. so not understandable.. :-)
